# Problemas con estructura de Bootstraps con fondos al 100%

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, css3

```css
.left .bg-nacimiento {
 background: #00c4c4;
    right: 0;
    height: 204px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    width: 52vw;
    z-index: -1;
}
.left .bg-guiness{
 background: #00b1b1;
    right: 0;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 203px;
    width: 100%;
    width: 52vw;
    z-index: -1;
}
.left .bg-reconocimiento{
 background: #009595;
    right: 0;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    width: 52vw;
    z-index: -1;
}
.left .nacimiento{
 position: absolute;
    bottom: 45px;
    padding-right: 22px;
}
.left .nacimiento i{
 font-size: 35px;
 color: #fff;
 margin-top: 7px;
}
.left .nacimiento h4{
 color: #fff;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 200;
}
.left .nacimiento p{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 13px;
}
.left .guiness h4{
 color: #fff;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 200;
}
.left .guiness p{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 13px;
}
.left .guiness{
 position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    padding-right: 22px;
}
.left .guiness i{
 font-size: 35px;
 color: #fff;
 margin-top: 7px;
}

.left .reconocimiento h4{
 color: #fff;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 200;
}
.left .reconocimiento p{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 13px;
}
.left .reconocimiento{
    position: absolute;
    top: 241px;
    padding-right: 22px;
}
.left .reconocimiento i{
 font-size: 35px;
 color: #fff;
 margin-top: 7px;
}

/*columna derecha*/
.right .bg-ayuda {
  background:#238491;
  left: 0;
  height: 510px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  width: 57vw;
  z-index: -1;
}
.right .ayuda{
 padding: 100px 19px;
}
.right .ayuda h3{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 27px;
}
.right .ayuda h2{
 color:#fff;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 font-size: 34px;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.right .ayuda p{
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
   
   <section>
      <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 hidden-xs left" style="height: 603px">

                  <div class="bg-nacimiento"></div>
                  <div class="nacimiento">
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                     <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                     <h4>Reconocimiento al Dr. Pasqualini</h4>
                     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="bg-guiness"></div>
                   <div class="guiness">
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                     <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                     <h4>Mas de 5000 Nacimientos</h4>
                     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="bg-reconocimiento"></div>
                   <div class="reconocimiento">
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                     <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                     <h4>Sabias que tenemos un record guiness?</h4>
                     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  </p>
                    </div>
                  </div> 

                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 hidden-xs right" style="height: 510px" >
                  <div class="bg-ayuda"></div>
                  <div class="ayuda">
                   <h3>LOREM IPSUM LOREM</h3>
                    <h2>Estamos aqui para ayudar</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris. </p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor </p>
                  </div>
                </div>              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Estoy teniendo problemas con el armado de esta estructura en bootstrap, si bien tome como ejemplo el siguiente código que adjunto, no se como hacer bien la división de los tres colores que lleguen al extremo. Si bien armé algo usando posicionamiento no se si esta bien empleado para que el contenido se logre adaptar bien mas que nada los problemas surgen en modo mobile. El ejemplo esta armado en el siguiente html [Pagina web](http://qkstudiodemo.com/halitus-html/)

```css
.row div {box-shadow:0 0 4px #000;}
.bg:before {position:absolute;left:0em; content:'';height:100%;width:800em;z-index:-1}
.bg-red:before {background-color:red;}
.bg-green:before {background-color:green;}
.bg-left:before {left:-400em;}
.bg-right:before {left:0;right:auto;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">4</div>
    <div class="col-md-8">8</div>
    <div class="col-md-7">7</div>
    <div class="col-md-5">5</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 bg bg-red bg-left">4</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 bg bg-green bg-right">8</div>
    <div class="col-md-7">7</div>
    <div class="col-md-5">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No he entendido muy bien tu pregunta, quieres que la caja grande tenga el mismo alto que las 3 cajas pequeñas juntas? No entiendo !!

Comment: Hola camilo como estas? mi problema es si lo que hice esta bien planteado el contenido de esa seccion. El problema surge cuando este maquetado de la seccion se hace responsive como lograr posicionar los elementos. si es necesario edito la pregunta y adjunto el código que use para su armado. Se comprende?

Comment: Exactamente cual es tu problema ? en el código que agregaste veo que las 4 cajas están bien !

Comment: Claro, si mas que nada es saber si lo estoy haciendo bien, porque estuve inspeccionandolo con el inspecto de chrome y ponele en 1920 se me va a la mierda y me genera un blanco.

Comment: Acabo de hacer eso y no me pasa